# drawRoundRect in Android not working

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, android-custom-view

I want to draw a rounded rectangle with drawRoundRect method in Android.

```
void drawRoundRect (RectF rect, float rx,  float ry, Paint paint)
```

I'm using Android Studio, and my testing device use Android 6.0.1, API 23

This is part of my code. It works find when I put zeros in rx and ry.

```
public void draw(Canvas canvas){
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(rect, 0, 0, pnt);
}
```

This draws a black rectangle in my screen.

But when I try to make it rounded,

```
public void draw(Canvas canvas){
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(rect, 10, 10, pnt);
}
```

It draws nothing. This only draws white background....

I tried different numbers like 100, 3, 5, 0.03f etc in rx and ry,

but any numbers bigger than 0 make drawRoundRect() not working.

Is there anything wrong with my code...?

Comment: Hey! did you found any solution?

Answer (score 6):

Make sure that coordinates in RectF that is used to draw rounded rectangle are correct. That means: `rect.left < rect.right` and `rect.top < rect.bottom`.

It seems that Android 7 corrects wrong coordinates itself and draws desired rounded rectangle, but Android 6 is drawing nothing if there is problem with coordinates.

Comment: THIS! Same code draws the rectangles fine on later versions of Android but breaks on 6.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this we have a little calculation but it works awesomely

```
private void drawRoundedRect(Canvas canvas, float left, float top, float right, float bottom) {
    float radius = getHeight() / 2;
    canvas.drawCircle(radius, radius, radius, mainPaint);
    canvas.drawCircle(right - radius, radius, radius, mainPaint);
    canvas.drawRect(left + radius, top, right - radius, bottom, mainPaint);
}
```

or you can check this

```
RectF rect = new RectF(10,10,20,20);
canvas.drawRoundRect(rect , 0, 0, mPaint);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                        600, // Width
                        300, // Height
                        Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 // Config
                );

                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
                canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
                Paint paint = new Paint();
                paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
                paint.setColor(Color.RED);
                paint.setAntiAlias(true);

                int offset = 50;
                RectF rectF = new RectF(
                        offset, // left
                        offset, // top
                        canvas.getWidth() - offset, // right
                        canvas.getHeight() - offset // bottom
                );
                int cornersRadius = 25;
                canvas.drawRoundRect(
                        rectF, // rect
                        cornersRadius, // rx
                        cornersRadius, // ry
                        paint // Paint
                );
                mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this,

`RectF rect = new RectF(0f, 0f, width, height);`

`canvas.drawRoundRect(rect , 0, 0, mPaint);`